# What’s it looking like in there? Vs What’s it look like in there?

Tags: sentence-construction

> What’s it looking like in there?
>   What’s it look like in there?

Or

> What’s it looking like inside the the dmv?
>   What’s it look like inside the dmv?

Are any of the grammatically correct?

Comment: Perhaps not *grammatically* correct, but this is commonly used phrasing in informal speech, and all four would be acceptable in quoted dialog. BTW, if DMV is Department of Motor Vehicles, a likely answer might be "The wait's two hours."

Comment: The first one is correct, but the second ("What’s it look like in there?") is colloquial. Technically not correct grammar.

Comment: To be syntactically valid, the second one should be *What **does it** it look like in there?*. But so many native speakers have "under-articulated" the "do-support" (sliding seamlessly through **/t/** to **/d/** to **/s/** with no intervening vowels) for so many generations that lots of speakers no longer even realize there's a ***does*** there to be "swallowed" anyway. You shouldn't normally *write* it like that, though, because in many cases that's misleading. Just because you can't hear my ***does*** doesn't mean I didn't *intend* it (and make at least a minimal attempt to enunciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct and sound natural when used correctly.

These questions are asking for the listener's impression of a place that the speaker does not know the current state of. There is a subtle difference between them though.

> What's it looking like in there?

This question is asking about how the status of a place has changed.

For example, imagine your roommate or spouse is cleaning a room. You know it was pretty messy earlier. You could ask "What's it looking like in there?" if you're curious if they are done cleaning or still have a lot of work to do. You are more concerned about how the room has changed or will change than what is actually looks like at the moment.

> What's it look like in there?

This question is focused on the current status of a place.

For example, imagine you meet someone you know at the DMV. They have just exited while you approach. Since the DMV has a reputation for being crowded and slow, you ask "What's it look like in there?" to get an impression of whether you'll need to wait or not. In this case, you probably don't know and don't care what the DMV was like earlier that day.

If in doubt, I suggest using the second question. It applies more broadly than the first.

Comment: Let’s say a nightclub for instance. If I’m not there and I’m asking someone to find out how it is. Would I say, what’s it looking like in there or what’s it look like in there? 
Thanks for that detailed response

Comment: I think this is largely a spurious semantic distinction. OP's second example is characteristic of casual speech (or sloppy writing). But it's just a stylistic choice, as are *"How's it look?"* or *"How's it looking?"* in the same context.